# RJAGS - Bayesian Beta binomial syntax

Tags: beta-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution

I am working on a classic problem when the posterior probability distribution of a proportion must be obtained. This parameters is assumed to followed a beta distribution, therefore the number of ocurrence is modelled by a beta-binomial distribution. I am using RJAGS to compute the posterior distribution and have some question about the syntax I have to use. The data I have is characterized for having number of occurrence (Y) and sampling size or number of observation (M) for each row.

The distribution of the observed failure rate (Y/M) is depicted in the following plot:

[image: Failure Rate Histogram]

As can be seen, it is left-skewed distribution with some observation to the right side showing larger proportion values. The quantiles for this parameters is the following:
[image: Failure Rate Quantiles]

The code of the first model is given by:

```
jags_model_syntax <-"model {
  # Likelihood
  for (i in 1:length(Y)) {
    Y[i] ~ dbin(p,N[i])
    N[i] <- M[i]  # Population size
    
  }
  
  p~dbeta(alpha,beta)
  alpha~dnorm(0.77,0.1)
  beta~dnorm(76,15)
}"
```

After compiling the model and computing the posterior, the results are the following. The probability distribution of p (the proportion) is a beta distribution and it is signficantly different to the distribution of the observed proportion.

[image: Posterior distribution]

I have following question:

- Should I give one probability to each lot, that means fitting a hierarchical model. This would change by adding a p[i] at each iteration
- Why beta distribution can not fit the original distribution?

Comment: I'm not sure the statement "the beta distribution can not fit the original distribution" is correct. One obvious issue is that the range of the x-axis in the histogram is (0, 0.1) while in the density plot of p, the x-axis range is (0.05). So histogram and the posterior density may "look different" just because the x-axis range is different.